# spring data creates unnecessary unique constraints

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application and using following User model class.

```
 @Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String emailAddress;
    private Boolean active;
    private String password;
    private boolean techLead;
    private boolean sdm;
    private boolean admin;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Circle> sdmForCircle;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Node> techLeadForNode;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Operator> userWorkingForOperator;

..................
```

Once i load the Spring boot application it is automatically creating  Tables for sdmForCircle ,userWorkingForOperator and  techLeadForNode but these tables are created with unnecessary unique constraints. I would like to stop unique constraints getting ADDED AUTOMATICALLY .

Please suggest .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want the uniqueness, use ManyToMany instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be turning off automatic ddl generation. 
You can do it by adding Spring Boot properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```